# How many bit strings of length $12$ have a substring $01$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, binary

My question is should it be $11C2$ or should it be $11C1$?

Since $01$ are connected together, I take them as a single unit and there are $11$ different positions where they can be placed. Is the answer $11C1$?

Comment: Hint. does your method give the right answer for bit strings of length 3? Work that case out by hand and generalize.

Comment: It would then be 10C1 or 10C3. The only way I can check my answer is correct if I can write a code for it or count them manually. I think it should be 10C1. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: See any of the answers below for an answer...

Comment: @user3525357 No, Ethan meant to work out the case "how many bit strings of length 3 have a substring 01".  This is very easy to check by hand.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who answered!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be easier to ask how many bit strings of length $n$ do not have the substring '01'.

I think of the bit string as a little plot, so $0100$ would be the graph $(0,0),(1,1),(2,0),(3,0)$. The substring $01$ corresponds to an upward jump in the graph. It follows that the only graphs that do not have an upward jump are those of the form $1^* 0^*$ (of the appropriate length, of course).

Hence the number of bit strings of length $n$ do not have the substring '01' is
$n+1$ (all ones, all ones except for last place, ..., all zeros).

Hence
the answer is $2^n-(n+1)$.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I understood how to solve this now. I would upvote but I have just joined this site and don't have enough points.

Answer (score 4):

Easier way to answer this: there are $2^{12}$ bitstrings. How many bitstrings **don't** have a substring $01$? To answer this: This means that a bitstring has to be either all $0$s, all $1$s, or has $n$ leading $1$s and $12-n$ following $0$s. (Like $100000000000$ through $111111111110$.)

There's only one bitstring that's all $0$s, and there's only one bitstring that's all $1$s. Then there are $11$ bitstrings for the leading-$1$-and-following-$0$ case. (Just count $100000000000$, $11000000000$, etc., or show it arithmetically.)

So there are $13$ bitstrings that don't have a $01$ substring. So there are $2^{12} - 13$ bitstrings that have a $01$ substring.

Comment: Thanks for the easy explanation!

Answer (score 3):

The critical observation is that a string that *lacks* the substring $01$ can only be a (possibly empty) substring of $1$'s, followed by a (possibly empty) substring of $0$'s.  If any $1$ comes after any $0$, then there must be a $01$ substring.  Therefore, there are only $13$ different bit strings that fail to have a substring $01$, and the total number of strings that satisfy the original condition is $2^{12}-13$.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I understood how to solve this now.

Answer (score 2):

I would attack this problem from left to right:

Let's suppose that my string starts with `0`, then we have a lot of possibilities that my string have the substring `01`, those are $(2^{11} - 1)$ (we have all the $2^{11}$ possibilities, except when all the $11$ bits left are all `0`s).

The next step I would take is supposing that my string starts with `10`, then we have another $(2^{10} - 1)$ possibilities, then we suppose that it starts with `110`, and so on...

At the end (last steps), my string starts with `11111111110`; ($10$ `1`s), so I have $2^1 - 1=1$ possibility for my string having the substring `01`, that's when my last bit is `1`.  Then I would have my beginning string like `11111111110` ($11$ `1`s), and there I have $2^0 - 1 = 0$ possibilities for having the `01` as a substring, and that's obvious because I have no available bits, and my string doesn't have the substring `01`.  And finally `111111111111` ($12$ `1`s) does not have the string '01` as a substring either.

So the answer is

$$\begin{align}
(2^{11} - 1) + (2^{10} - 1)+ & \ldots + (2^0 - 1) \\ 
&= (2^{11} + 2^{10} + \ldots + 2^0) - \overbrace{(1+1+ \ldots +1)}^{12 \text{ times}} \\ 
&= (2^{12} - 1) - 12 \\
&= 2^{12} - 13 = 4083
\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes: at the end (last steps), my string start with '11111111110' (10 1's and 1 '0'), so I have 2"1 - 1 possibilities for my string having the substring '01', that is 1 possibility (that's when my last bit is '1').

Then I whould have my begining string like '11111111110' (11 1's and 1 '0'), and there I have 2"1 - 1 posibilities for having the '01' as a substring, and that's obvious because i have not avaliable bits, and my string has not the substring '01'.

And my last string is '111111111111' (12 1's), and that one does not have the string '01' as a substring.

Comment: (2"11 - 1) + (2"10 - 1) + ... + (2"0 - 1) = (2"11 + 2"10 + ... + 2"0) - (1+1+1... [12 times]) = (2"12 - 1) - 12 = 2"12 - 13

You are welcome :)

Comment: I think we now have an excellent answer :-) You can review with "edit" to see the formatting codes.

Answer (score 0):

The number of strings with the first $01$ occurring at the $1$st position:

- $01XXXXXXXXXX$
- Therefore, it is $1\cdot2^{10}$

---

The number of strings with the first $01$ occurring at the $2$nd position:

- $001XXXXXXXXX$
- $101XXXXXXXXX$
- Therefore, it is $2\cdot2^{9}$

---

The number of strings with the first $01$ occurring at the $3$rd position:

- $0001XXXXXXXX$
- $1001XXXXXXXX$
- $1101XXXXXXXX$
- Therefore, it is $3\cdot2^{8}$

---

The number of strings with the first $01$ occurring at the $4$th position:

- $00001XXXXXXX$
- $10001XXXXXXX$
- $11001XXXXXXX$
- $11101XXXXXXX$
- Therefore, it is $4\cdot2^{7}$

---

And so forth...

So the general formula is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{11}n\cdot2^{11-n}=4083$.

Since the total number of strings is $2^{12}=4096$, there is probably an easier way to derive this.

Comment: Whoever down-voted this: it's the same as all up-voted answers above, so please don't down-vote unless you leave a comment explaining it!!!

Comment: Hey barak, I upvoted not because your answer is the same, but because it's different. So you're a little bit ahead now :-)

Comment: @Joffan: Thank you. The final outcome is the same as in other answers here, **and** correct. That's why I was annoyed with the unreasoned down-vote (in fact, the "unreasoning" would be annoying even if the outcome **was** wrong). On top of that, the solution method is indeed different, and as you have implied (if I understood you correctly), it simply contributes a different perspective to this post.